# align two table rows when table is centered

Tags: html, html-table

I want to align the date and Summer clearance inside of this table but I want to keep the table centered of the image horizontally. I am open for not using a table to achieve the same effect but I can;'t use Flex. It needs to be supported in most emails.

```css
.outer {
  position:relative;
  background-color:red;
  display:block;
  width:650px;
  background-image:url(https://blog.prezi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/1_pzUhL5WpOeViwICDDgiLUA.jpeg)
}
.inner {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:pink;
  display:block;
  bottom:-25px;
  right:50%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  margin:auto;
  
}
.hidden{
  visibility:hidden;
}
#img-text{
                position:absolute;
                bottom:40px;
                margin:auto;
                width:100%;
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color:#ffffff;
        text-align:center;
                
            }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="outer">
        <img class="hidden" src="https://blog.prezi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/1_pzUhL5WpOeViwICDDgiLUA.jpeg">
            <table id="img-text" align="center">
                                <tr><td>8/30-9/1</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>SUMMMER CLEARANCE</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><h3>20% OFF</h3></td></tr>
                                </table>
        <div class="inner">Hello</div>
      </div> 
     
    </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

This is what Ive got to work with. Ive tried using margin:auto and text-align with wrappers but can't find a way to align it left in the middle of the image.

Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

#img-text tr td { text-align: left ; }
you can target table data inside it and set align as you wish

Comment: when doing this though the td aligns all the way to the left of the image. I want it to be centered but aligned left.

Comment: this issue cause your position : absolute ;  it's so easy if it setted to display: flex ;  but if you want your code to be as it , the solution is to set #img-text { left : 42% ; } as example